# Automated obscuring of PDF content

Tags: pdf, image-manipulation

I'm looking for a tool which will allow me to automate the task of obscuring a certain section of content contained within a PDF. The PDF content is essentially one big image which contains some sensitive information, and it is this information we need to ensure is not readable.

Any tips for where I should start looking for such a solution?

Many thanks

M

Comment: Just don't do it like the TSA ;-) http://news.slashdot.org/story/09/12/08/0057253/TSAs-Sloppy-Redacting-Reveals-All

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safe redacting tools/apis are available widely:

http://www.evermap.com/autoredact.asp

http://www.bravaviewer.com/redaction.htm

http://www.rapidredact.com/ahottopic.asp

Comment: Thanks very much. Now that I know to use the term 'redaction' I've suddenly found quite a few tools that claim to do what we need - now just the process  of evaluating all of them.


Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Just to say that we ended up using [Autoredact from Evermap](http://www.evermap.com/autoredact.asp) which turned out to be a very capable product.

It gets even more powerful if you use the document automation routines which Acrobat Pro allows. And you can take it a step further if you use the [AutoBatch](http://www.evermap.com/autobatch.asp) product from the same guys.

Hopefully this helps anyone in the future searching for the same functionality (probably will be me 3 years later).

M